# Page does not reload on state change inside jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have seen several questions with the same title but not the same problem,

I wrote some react code and inside return method's jsx, inside select onchange
I called a function that setstate but the page will not reload although I made sure the state is changed

jsx code inside return:

`<select defaultValue={book.shelf} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, book)}`

code inside contructor

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);}
```

code inside component

```
 handleChange = (e, book) => {
 BooksAPI.update(book, e.target.value).then(this.setState(
     { value: e.target.value, book: book },
     () => console.log(this.state.value)
   ));
```

};

Knowing that this.state.value prints correctly and the value is returned from the API and it is different from the previous state's value

What could be the problem,

Any help appreciated.

Edit:
My full select code

```js
<select defaultValue={book.shelf} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, book)}>
                        <option value="move" disabled>
                          Move to...
                        </option>
                        <option value="currentlyReading">
                          Currently Reading
                        </option>
                        <option value="wantToRead">Want to Read</option>
                        <option value="read">Read</option>
                        <option value="none">None</option>
                      </select>
```

Edit 2:

This is my state

```
 state = {
    books: [],
    value: '',
    book: {},
    update: false,
  };
```

Final edit:

To prevent confusion the problem was with my UI unrelated to this code

Comment: I think your select needs a `value` prop

Comment: I added a defaultvalue isn't it enough

Comment: You need to pass a **function** to `then()`

Comment: handleChange = (e, book) => {
     BooksAPI.update(book, e.target.value).then((book)=>
       this.setState(
         { value: book.shelf },
         () => console.log(book.shelf)
       ));
  };
same problem

Comment: So the reason was something with my UI unrelated to this code just saying so that no one gets confused by my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```js
handleChange = (e, book) => {
 BooksAPI.update(book, e.target.value).then(this.setState(
     { value: e.target.value, book: book },
     () => console.log(this.state.value)
   ));
```

Change it to this

```js
handleChange = (e, book) => {
 BooksAPI.update(book, e.target.value).then(() => {
    this.setState(
     { value: e.target.value, book: book },
     () => console.log(this.state.value)
   )
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, The problem was unrelated to this code it was the UI

Comment: But actually this improves the code so I will mark it as answered for this reason